# Linux kernel ftrace irqsoff tracer generates strange output

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I was analyzing the interrupt latency in my system( Freescale ARM MX6Q with linux kernel version 3.0.35), I am using the irqsoff tracer, and this is the output I'm getting for the biggest irq off latency:

```
# tracer: irqsoff
#
# irqsoff latency trace v1.1.5
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# latency: 2770 us, #89/89, CPU#0 | (M:preempt VP:0, KP:0, SP:0 HP:0 #P:4)
#    -----------------
#    | task: swapper-0 (uid:0 nice:0 policy:0 rt_prio:0)
#    -----------------
#  => started at: tick_oneshot_mode_active
#  => ended at:   default_idle
#
#
#                  _------=> CPU#            
#                 / _-----=> irqs-off        
#                | / _----=> need-resched    
#                || / _---=> hardirq/softirq 
#                ||| / _--=> preempt-depth   
#                |||| /     delay             
#  cmd     pid   ||||| time  |   caller      
#     \   /      |||||  \    |   /           
  <idle>-0       0d..1    1us : tick_oneshot_mode_active
  <idle>-0       0d..1    2us : clockevents_notify <-arch_idle
  <idle>-0       0d..1    3us : _raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-clockevents_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..1    5us : __raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-_raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..1    6us : add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..2    7us : clockevents_do_notify <-clockevents_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2    8us : raw_notifier_call_chain <-clockevents_do_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2   10us : __raw_notifier_call_chain <-raw_notifier_call_chain
  <idle>-0       0d..2   11us : notifier_call_chain <-__raw_notifier_call_chain
  <idle>-0       0d..2   12us : tick_notify <-notifier_call_chain
  <idle>-0       0d..2   13us : tick_broadcast_oneshot_control <-tick_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2   15us : _raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..2   16us : __raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-_raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..2   17us+: add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..3   19us : clockevents_set_mode <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..3   20us : twd_set_mode <-clockevents_set_mode
  <idle>-0       0d..3   21us : irq_modify_status <-gic_disable_ppi
  <idle>-0       0d..3   22us : __irq_get_desc_lock <-irq_modify_status
  <idle>-0       0d..3   24us : irq_to_desc <-__irq_get_desc_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..3   25us : _raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-__irq_get_desc_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..3   26us : __raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-_raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..3   27us : add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..4   29us : __irq_put_desc_unlock <-irq_modify_status
  <idle>-0       0d..4   30us : _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore <-__irq_put_desc_unlock
  <idle>-0       0d..4   31us : sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  <idle>-0       0d..3   32us : irq_get_irq_data <-gic_disable_ppi
  <idle>-0       0d..3   34us : irq_to_desc <-irq_get_irq_data
  <idle>-0       0d..3   35us : gic_mask_irq <-gic_disable_ppi
  <idle>-0       0d..3   36us : _raw_spin_lock <-gic_mask_irq
  <idle>-0       0d..3   37us : __raw_spin_lock <-_raw_spin_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..3   39us : add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..4   40us : _raw_spin_unlock <-gic_mask_irq
  <idle>-0       0d..4   41us+: sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock
  <idle>-0       0d..3   43us : _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..3   44us : sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  <idle>-0       0d..2   45us+: _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore <-clockevents_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2   47us : sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  <idle>-0       0d..1   48us+: mxc_cpu_lp_set <-arch_idle
  <idle>-0       0d..1   50us+: gpc_mask_single_irq <-mxc_cpu_lp_set
  <idle>-0       0d..1   51us+: gpc_mask_single_irq <-mxc_cpu_lp_set
  <idle>-0       0d..1   53us+: arch_idle_multi_core <-arch_idle
  <idle>-0       0d..1   55us!: ca9_do_idle <-arch_idle_multi_core
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2709us : clockevents_notify <-arch_idle
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2710us : _raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-clockevents_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2711us : __raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-_raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2712us+: add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2714us : clockevents_do_notify <-clockevents_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2715us : raw_notifier_call_chain <-clockevents_do_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2716us : __raw_notifier_call_chain <-raw_notifier_call_chain
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2717us : notifier_call_chain <-__raw_notifier_call_chain
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2718us : tick_notify <-notifier_call_chain
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2720us : tick_broadcast_oneshot_control <-tick_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2721us : _raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2722us : __raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-_raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2723us : add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2725us : clockevents_set_mode <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2726us : twd_set_mode <-clockevents_set_mode
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2727us : irq_modify_status <-gic_enable_ppi
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2729us : __irq_get_desc_lock <-irq_modify_status
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2730us : irq_to_desc <-__irq_get_desc_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2731us : _raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-__irq_get_desc_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2732us : __raw_spin_lock_irqsave <-_raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2733us+: add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock_irqsave
  <idle>-0       0d..4 2738us+: __irq_put_desc_unlock <-irq_modify_status
  <idle>-0       0d..4 2739us : _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore <-__irq_put_desc_unlock
  <idle>-0       0d..4 2741us : sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2742us : irq_get_irq_data <-gic_enable_ppi
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2743us : irq_to_desc <-irq_get_irq_data
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2745us : gic_unmask_irq <-gic_enable_ppi
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2746us : _raw_spin_lock <-gic_unmask_irq
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2747us : __raw_spin_lock <-_raw_spin_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2748us+: add_preempt_count <-__raw_spin_lock
  <idle>-0       0d..4 2750us : _raw_spin_unlock <-gic_unmask_irq
  <idle>-0       0d..4 2751us+: sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2753us : ktime_get <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2754us+: clocksource_mmio_readl_up <-ktime_get
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2756us : tick_program_event <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2757us : tick_dev_program_event <-tick_program_event
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2758us : ktime_get <-tick_dev_program_event
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2759us+: clocksource_mmio_readl_up <-ktime_get
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2761us : clockevents_program_event <-tick_dev_program_event
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2762us : twd_set_next_event <-clockevents_program_event
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2764us : _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore <-tick_broadcast_oneshot_control
  <idle>-0       0d..3 2765us+: sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2767us : _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore <-clockevents_notify
  <idle>-0       0d..2 2768us : sub_preempt_count <-_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2769us+: default_idle
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2772us+: trace_hardirqs_on <-default_idle
  <idle>-0       0d..1 2773us : <stack trace>
 => trace_hardirqs_on
 => default_idle
 => cpu_idle
 => rest_init
 => start_kernel
 =>
```

So according to ftrace I have a pretty big latency, it looks as if the interrupts are disabled as long as the CPU is idle. So I thought surely this cannot be true, so I looked more closely at function tick_oneshot_mode_active:

```
int tick_oneshot_mode_active(void)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    int ret;

    local_irq_save(flags);
    ret = __this_cpu_read(tick_cpu_device.mode) == TICKDEV_MODE_ONESHOT;
    local_irq_restore(flags);

    return ret;
}
```

So in the macro local_irq_save, the interrupts are disabled and the function trace_hardirqs_off() is called which registers that the interrupts were disabled:

```
#define local_irq_save(flags)               \
    do {                        \
        raw_local_irq_save(flags);      \
        trace_hardirqs_off();           \
    } while (0)
```

After checking the device mode the interrupts are enabled, now here it is strange:

```
#define local_irq_restore(flags)            \
    do {                        \
        if (raw_irqs_disabled_flags(flags)) {   \
            raw_local_irq_restore(flags);   \
            trace_hardirqs_off();       \
        } else {                \
            trace_hardirqs_on();        \
            raw_local_irq_restore(flags);   \
        }                   \
    } while (0)
```

In my case the code goes over the first branch:

```
if (raw_irqs_disabled_flags(flags)) {   \
                raw_local_irq_restore(flags);   \
                trace_hardirqs_off();       \
```

It looks as if even though the interrupts are enabled back, function trace_hardirqs_on is not called but trace_hardirqs_off(). Why is this happening, do I really have this big latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with the same problem, and I patch kernel with this:

https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/5/25/83

after that idle disappear from trace.